# sshd_config settings not taking effect

Tags: linux, ssh, sftp, sshd

I've been trying to configure SSH public key authentication for non-interactive login for sftp and for that to work, I know I need to have the following settings:

```
RSAAuthentication yes
PubkeyAuthentication yes
AuthorizedKeysFile  .ssh/authorized_keys
```

I've already added the generated public key to the authorized_keys on the remote server and when I try to run a ssh command or sftp command. I'm still prompted for my password. I'm seeing the following when I run the ssh command with -vvv

```
2014-10-08 10:05:37  debug(2) pid=23469 Querying server for authmethod - publickey
2014-10-08 10:05:37  debug(2) pid=23469 Query for publickey failed -- publickey disabled.
2014-10-08 10:05:37  debug(2) pid=23469 Querying server for authmethod - password
```

I take it that the sshd_config settings isn't taking effect? Can someone advice me on this?

Thanks!

Comment: You should check server logs, on Debian / Ubuntu `/var/log/auth.log` CentOS Redhat I think `/var/log/secure` it's probably a ownership / permissions issue on the  `.ssh/authorized_keys`

Comment: Did you restart `sshd`?

Comment: AFTER making the sshd_config changes did you restart the sshd service?  Changes do not take effect until a restart.

Comment: @Jan
Yes I've restarted SSHD using the command 
`service sshd restart`

Comment: @mdpc yep I've restarted SSHD

Comment: @Shutupsquare The only meaningful message on my /var/log/secure is that the connection is closed. What permission should my authorized keys file be? Mine is currently set to 600

Comment: Would like to see the actual file (sshd_config). That helps. Causes that you can find to this problem range from not uncommenting the properties to actually having edited the wrong file (ssh_config).

Comment: Thanks for that, @Jan. Had same issue, forgot to restartd SSHD, restart fixed it.